# Fill data in html php table from POST

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table, http-post

I want to fill data in the table. I get the values from Sessions and the POST.

There is the method where I am getting the values I want to put in the table.

```
if ( isset($_POST) ) {

    //$valuee[] = array();  
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
        //$valuee[] = str_split($value, 3); 
        var_dump($value);
        //extract($valuee);
    { 
        $cr = explode( "&",$key ); // ◄■■ SPLIT : [0]="CORP_RESP",[1]="1".
    }

    mysqli_query( $con,"insert into respostas 
                            (menuid,corp_resp,id,data,
                            id_avaliacao) " . 
                        "values ('{$cr[1]}','$value', '{$cr[2]}', 
                                 '{$cr[5]}', '{$cr[3]}')" );
}
```

That is the output I want to put in the table from `var_dump($value)`.

> string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.45" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.50" string(4) "0.65" string(4) "0.75" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.60" string(4) "0.65" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.00" string(4) "0.60"

There is code where is building the table. That table is dynamic according what is select before the POST. The code need to handle with the number of columns and lines.

```
$s2 = $_SESSION['categorias'];
$utilizador = $_SESSION['utilizador'];
$uCount = $_SESSION['cparametro']; 
$carCount = $_SESSION['ncategoria'];

$table ="<center><table><tr><center><td>Parametro</td></center>";

for($x = 0; $x < $carCount; $x++){
    $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$x], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $table= $table."<td>".$val."</td>";
}

$table = $table."</tr>";
for($i = 0 ; $i <$uCount ; $i++ ){
    $table = $table."<tr><td>".$utilizador[$i]."</td>";

    for($j=0;$j<$carCount;$j++){

        $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$j], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        $table = $table."<td>";
        $table = $table.$value;
        $table = $table."</td>";
    }    
}


$table = $table."</tr>";
$teste = "Resultado";
$table= $table."<center><td>$teste</td></center>";

$table = $table."</table>";
echo $table;
```

Where is `$table = $table.$value;` need to pass the values correct all is before in the fills and not passing only the last one? The rest of the table is correct.

Like you see in the picture what is the output:

Before the POST:

[image]

After the POST:

[image]

New output:

[image]

Comment: please add a full table screenshot, so I can verify if my answer will help you

Comment: Hello @ThomasLang, i add before and after. What i want is put that values from select options in the print table.

Answer (score 0):

This seems awfully complicated, which results in not being able to identify the problem, but In short;
the problem is you are using:

```
$table = $table.$value;
```

but $value is not the correct variable, you should use:

```
$table = $table.$val;
```

Longer idea:
If you would like to improve your code you could use this notation:

```
$table.= "append to the var"
```

instead of:

```
$table = $table . "append to var"
```

It makes it a lot more readable, but I think you could simplify it even more..

why do you have $carcount and $s2?

I think $carcount will tell you how many categories are in $s2, but you could just use count($s2) instead, this will reduce the amount of code, also for $uCount and $utilizador

This will do the same, and starts to get more readable, I'm sure it can be simlified even more, but this is what I could do in a few minutes:

```
$s2 = $_SESSION['categorias'];
$utilizador = $_SESSION['utilizador'];


$table ="<table><tr><center><td>Parametro</td>";

foreach($s2 as $cat){
    $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$cat], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $table.= "<td>".$val."</td>";
}

$table .= "</tr>";
foreach($utilizador as $util){
    $table.= "<tr><td>".$util."</td>";

    foreach($s2 as $cat){

        $val= htmlspecialchars($cat), ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
        $table.="<td>$val</td>";

    }    
}

$table.= "</tr>";
$table.= "<td>Resultado</td>";

$table.="</table>";
echo $table;
```

It would be even nicer if you would put this in a function, and call that function from where you need the table.

Comment: Hello @Thomas Lang, the problem is how to get the value from the POST -> $value and put in the table where is  $table = $table.$value; You understand my idea? After i will change the code for reduce that.

Comment: Yes Christophe, but it's called $val:   $val= htmlspecialchars($s2[$j], ENT_HTML5 | ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'); in your code, not $value :) if you want to set the $value from the $_POST you will need to add that inside the foreach of the $_POST, now it will fill the table with the last value of your $_POST